# Error JobRunShell.cs not found at HttpContextWrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, quartz.net, httpcontext

I using Quartz .NET to execute code every minute and also refresh Index page after code execution, Quartz working fine to execute code but error while redirect to Index page (UI).

Complete code is :

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);

    try
    {
        // construct a scheduler factory
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        // get a scheduler
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<NotificationJob>()
            .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
            .Build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 60 seconds
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
              .WithIntervalInSeconds(60)
              .RepeatForever())
          .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e) { }
}
```

**NotificationJob.cs**

```
public class NotificationJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext Context)
    {
       // Code execution logic here...

        // Redirect to Index page
        var context = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), new RouteData());
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);
        var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Error occurs at `new HttpContextWrapper`.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you use Nuget to reference Quartz?

Comment: Yes @S.Dav I'm using Nuget to reference Quartz.

Comment: Quartz 2.x or 3?

Comment: @Rabban it's Quartz 2.5.0

Comment: I would guess this comes through a bug in your job and has nothing to do with quartz. Debug your `NotificationJob` and you will see where it will throw the exception and was the real issue is. Maybe the `HttpContext` is null or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz jobs have no way of accessing HttpContext. They work outside of HttpContext, in separate threads.